# How to call events inside stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamicquery

I want to run multiple events in different schemas. I am trying to use the events inside in one stored procedure. So that I can execute one Sp for all the schemas. But I am getting **"Recursion of EVENT DDL statements is forbidden when body is present"** this error.

Comment: You cannot fire an event manually. You can create a stored procedure for everything an event does, and let both the event and your stored procedure just call that procedure. Also: please add your code. Your error message implies that you are trying to create the events (not execute them).

Comment: Can you please share some examples for above mentioned issue.

Comment: I mean: create a procedure `A` (which does everything your event shall do). Then create your event, which will just consist of one line that calls procedure `A`. If you want to execute that event manually (e.g. in another procedure), you just call procedure `A` there too.

Comment: I have created the procedure where all the event related logic written. I Created event that one is calling the procedure internally. it's working fine .Thanks.